# Redirect my site according to Country

Tags: geolocation

I want to redirect my website according to location so as to display pages and price plans according to place like for Indian users price should be in INR and for US.

What is the best way or script to implement this?

Comment: You're confusing two different issues. Currency corresponds with location because it relates to jurisdiction, so the choice of INR or USD based on locality makes sense (esp. if done as a default with the option to override), but language only correlates with location and a given person in China might prefer English while someone in the US might prefer Chinese, so you should base that on the accept-language header not locality, and again with an override.

Comment: (And that language override shouldn't be represented with a flag; again locality != language but also some people have negative reactions to some flags, and also the text is its own quick-to-spot UI: Everyone who reads English will understand the word "English", everyone who reads Chinese will understand the word "中文", and so on).

Comment: I want both the two features.  This means i will have to create English and Chinese pages for Chinese audience. Plus a currency specific page for currency. Please suggest how i should proceed.

Comment: Sorry but this question is too board and good answers would be too long for this format. You may be able to save the question by editing it and making it more specific and less board as well as a little opinionated 'best way type questions' it should be also noted that recommendation of plugins, scripts and services are considered off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Geolify dot com provides such solutions. They are quite affordable & are ready to customize the scripts depending on your requirements. Consider initiating a chat with them and see if they suit your requirements.

Comment: For geolocation i think i will use free Geoip database. but not sure about how to manage redirect according to language and currency wise.